# Transforming Non-Uniformly Sampled Image onto Rectangular Grid

Tags: image-processing, image-registration, projection

I have an image and associated latitude and longitude matrices. So I know the latitude and longitude of every pixel. However, due to the camera orientation, the image is skewed and thus the latitude and longitude sampling is non-linear. See the images below. I want to resample this image on rectangular, evenly sampled latitude-longitude grid. I have coded up a way to do this, but it's computationally expensive, and I feel certain that there must be a better way. I've done quite a bit of searching, but I haven't found good hits. Perhaps I just don't know the lingo necessary for the right search terms.

The image below is the original image.
[image]

I want to get a resampled image that looks something like this:
[image]

I produced this image, by basically moving a square boolean mask across the original image and finding the mean of the values as shown below:
[image]

Ideally, I think that pixels with mostly empty space should have an opacity value as well, but let's table that for now. Here's the MATLAB code I wrote to do this:

```
%% Create Skewed Image - All of These Are Knowns
rows = 1:size(frame, 1);
cols = 1:size(frame, 2);

% Create non-linearly sampled grid
lat_grid = zeros(size(frame));
lon_grid = zeros(size(frame));
for r = 1:numel(rows)
    for c = 1:numel(cols)
        lat_grid(r,c) = 0 + .001*rows(r) + 1e-3*cols(c) + 1e-6 * rows(r).^2;
        lon_grid(r,c) = 0 + .001*cols(c) + 1e-3*rows(r) + 1e-6 * cols(c).^2;
    end
end

h = figure; surf(lon_grid, lat_grid, frame, 'edgecolor','none'), view([0,90]), 
colormap(gray(256))
set(gca, 'ydir', 'reverse')
ylabel('Latitude (deg)')
xlabel('Longitude (deg)')
hold on
filename = 'testAnimated.gif';

%% Create image in target grid
target_lat_array = 0:0.1:(max(lat_grid(:))+0.1);
target_lon_array = 0:0.1:(max(lon_grid(:))+0.1);
[target_lon_grid, target_lat_grid] = meshgrid(target_lon_array, target_lat_array);
resampled_frame = zeros(size(target_lon_grid));
n = 0;
for r = 2:size(target_lat_grid, 1)
    for c = 2:size(target_lon_grid, 2)
        n = n + 1;
        mask = ((lon_grid > target_lon_grid(r, c-1)) & (lon_grid < target_lon_grid(r, c))) & ((lat_grid > target_lat_grid(r-1, c)) & (lat_grid < target_lat_grid(r, c)));
        ph = patch(...
        [target_lon_grid(r, c-1), target_lon_grid(r, c-1), target_lon_grid(r, c), target_lon_grid(r, c)],...
        [target_lat_grid(r-1, c), target_lat_grid(r, c), target_lat_grid(r, c), target_lat_grid(r-1, c)],...
        [1e4, 1e4, 1e4, 1e4], [1,0,0,0.5]);
        if ~any(mask(:))
            delete(ph)
            continue
        end

        % Write to the GIF File 
        im = frame2im(getframe(h)); 
        [imind,cm] = rgb2ind(im,256); 
        if n == 1 
            imwrite(imind,cm,filename,'gif', 'Loopcount',inf); 
        else 
            imwrite(imind,cm,filename,'gif','WriteMode','append'); 
        end 

        delete(ph)
        resampled_frame(r-1, c-1) = mean(frame(mask));
    end
end

figure, imagesc(target_lon_array, target_lat_array, resampled_frame), 
colormap(gray(256)), axis image
ylabel('Latitude (deg)')
xlabel('Longitude (deg)')
```

Anybody have any ideas? Like I said, I just feel certain that there must be industry-standard ways to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to achieve something called **interpolation** and this can be done in roughly one line using MATLAB.

Interpolation is well explained over the web so I won't detail the functioning in this answer ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation) page is very complete and redirect to many interpolation methods, [here](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html) is the MATLAB documentation for 2D interpolation).

In a nutshell you parse as input both old locations (your longitude and latitude) and the data (the color corresponding to each location) as well as new locations (the rectangular and linear grid you want) and interpolation returns the new values corresponding to these locations.

Old locations could be either linear or non-linear as well as for the output locations. Moreover You can either ask for fewer or more points as the input number.

You should read carefully the documentation to address potential drawbacks of interpolation and to take account of the different methods available.

**Note:** if you have scattered data instead of gridded data you should use [this function](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html) instead of `interp2`.

---

Here is an example with a non-linear sampled sine on 50 points.

The red plot shows a linear resampling that keeps the original number of points (same resolution) but some information is lost near $\pi/2$ as the new sampling rate is lower than the original one at this location.

The green curve illustrates a linear resampling with a greater number of points (150).This time less information is lost but more points are extrapolated between original ones (near $0.5$ and $2.5$).

[image]

Note that it is a trivial example to illustrate the possibilities given by `interp1`. it does not shows properly why information can be lost or extrapolated.

Comment: Lous, thank you for the help. I considered interpolation, but I am concerned that it would be a poor sampling. Interpolation is only going to use the points very close to the target grid. Given that the target grid is a much more course resolution. How do I use interpolation to use more of the points in the source image that intersect with the target grid?

Comment: First there is a missconception in your last sentence as in the general case interpolation doesn't "keep" source point that intersect with the grid, it creates new ones bases on the neiborhood and a method (neareast neigbor, linear, cubic...). Secondly if you want to keep as much detail as possible you have to choose a grid with a sampling rate smaller than the highest source image sampling rate.

Comment: I edited my answer to briefly explain this.

Comment: Louis, I understand that interpolation doesn't keep the source point. My concern is that when interpolated to such a lower res grid, that using only neighborhood points from the source image is very unrepresentative.

Comment: Well, sorry if I'm wrong but your question may be unclear. Based on your comment I think what you actually want is to **downsample** your original image to a linearly sampled (that is something like 14x14 according to your question). I'm right? Otherwise please edit your question to be more specific.

Comment: Your problem is closely related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384991/what-is-the-best-image-downscaling-algorithm-quality-wise) (quite) old SE question as the algorithm you implemented is similar and targets the same goal (except the fact that you have a non-linear sampling). It contains many pieces of answers like this [link](https://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/image-interpolation.htm) that explains _Digital Image Interpolation_. Last but not least here is the Wikipedia page dealing with [Image Scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling).

Comment: Yes, I want to downsample. Thanks for your help and all the detail you gave it!